# Structuring Single-File/Header-Only Libraries in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, header-only

Is it considered good practice to structure single-file/header-only libraries in C++ such that they are conditionally either the header or the implementation? For example,

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_HEADER_HPP_
#define LIBRARY_HEADER_HPP_

// Header

struct Test {
    void test(); 
};

#endif // LIBRARY_HEADER_HPP_

#ifdef LIBRARY_IMPLEMENTATION_
#undef LIBRARY_IMPLEMENTATION_

// Implementation

void Test::test() {

}

#endif // LIBRARY_IMPLEMENTATION_
```

The user of the library would therefore `#define LIBRARY_IMPLEMENTATION` before **one** `#include "Library.hpp"` in a single implementation file, to avoid multiple definitions.

I've seen this strategy used in C libraries ([STB](https://github.com/nothings/stb) comes to mind), but I was wondering whether this would be considered idiomatic in modern C++ (or if there are better strategies for creating single-file/header-only libraries).

Comment: What problem is this supposed to solve?

Comment: Who does single header libraries in modern C++?

Comment: @PeteBecker I suppose ease of use (drop and go, instead of integrating sources into a build system).

Comment: @ddriver Whenever templates are used (which have to go in headers)

Comment: @AUD_FOR_IUV: Integrating sources into build systems? It's a `.cpp` file. It doesn't even have to be a static library. If a user can't manage to add a source file to their build system, they've got bigger problems than using your library.

Comment: @NicolBolas So is there simply no use at all? Are libraries like the aforementioned STB not worth constructing in such a way?

Comment: I think its not future oriented. Sooner or later there will be modules, without any preprocessor, which require each header to be separated.